# How to add products and display them on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, json, e-commerce, product

I know they say there's no stupid questions but here's one. Let's say you're coding a website from scratch with only html, css and js.

What are the ways to add and display products on a website?

I saw some people add them in the HTML and I saw some who make a JSON file for the products and display them through JavaScript.

Now, are those the only ways? and what's the best or your personal favorite way? Keep in mind that you need to keep track of the inventory and the amount of each product in stock.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: _"What are the ways to add and display products on a website?"_ there are too many to answer really. May you narrow down your question please?

Comment: Well, can you do it with only JavaScript?  @evolutionxbox

Comment: Not only JavaScript, no. This is because all websites need to output to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those two ways are when you want to build a static page and don't expect it to update or test a quick little feature. Later when your data grows

for example: you add multiple products to the inventory.

You need to look how to build apis and Create, Read, Update, Delete (CRUD) operations. There are lot of resources available on youtube/google search on how to use apis and get items through api calls.

Answer (score 0):

Add them in HTML by hand? If you must track inventory, stock etc then a database is a must. For example, [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/3) is a very popular choice, and gives you a free tier of 512 MB,managed in the cloud. Good luck!

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks for letting me know. I'm only a couple months into javascript and was wondering if there's a way to do it with only using javascript and keep track of inventory. So is that possible or nah? @pierpy

Comment: Yes, possible... but you must hardcode all that by hand, or reinvent the wheel for CRUD ops in a text/json document